# DNN - how to write file path ? (ResXResourceWriter)

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I try to create an `ResXResourceWriter` instance. using this code

```
ResXResourceWriter resxWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(filepath);
```

The file is located in local resources folder.

How to write the path?

Comment: Where are you using this line of code?  Is it in a module view that inherits PortalModuleBase?  There is an attribute of PortalModuleBase called LocalResourceFile that refers to the module view's resource file.  There are also other methods in DotNetNuke.Services.Localization that can help you.

Comment: in a Setting.ascx.cs file